# Unable to connect to GCP VM through IAP Desktop after installing our docker services

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

We have a GCP account with couple of VM's created. And we have one Linux VM with RHEL based OS. We connect to that VM using IAP Desktop app. After connecting through I performed the below steps

1. Disable SELinux
2. Reboot the machine
3. Install our docker services by a shell script

Then after installing our services I re-booted the machine. But it fails to connect through IAP Desktop

It throws error as bellow

[image: Connection Failure Error Message]

I tried accessing the machine through SSH client from another windows VM on the same network. That also did not work.

Not sure how to resolve this issue and connect to that machine?

As mentioned earlier I could connect to that VM using IAP Desktop initially and it works fine. After installing our services we could not connect to that.

Note: This happens to all RHEL OS VM's in GCP after installing our services

Comment: KBNanda : Has this helped to resolve your issue? let me know whether the shared info was helpful. I am happy to assist if you have any further queries.

Answer (score 0):

In order to connect to the SSH, you need to [create a firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding#create-firewall-rule) which `allows the port 22` that will help you in connecting through SSH and also as per official docs.

To allow IAP to connect to your VM instances, create a firewall rule that:

> - Applies to all VM instances that you want to be accessible by using IAP.
> - Allows ingress traffic from the IP range `35.235.240.0/20`. This range contains all IP addresses that IAP uses for TCP forwarding.
> - Allows connections to all ports that you want to be accessible by using IAP TCP forwarding, for example, port `22` for SSH and port `3389` for RDP.